# Designing of Serial-in/Serial-out Shift Register using RAM

Tags: digital-logic, shift-register

Design a 1024 bit serial-in/serial-out unidirectional shift register using a 1K × 1 bit RAM with a data input D<sub>in</sub>, data output  D<sub>out</sub> and control input READ/WRITE'. You may assume the availability of standard SSI and  MSI components such as gates, registers and counters.

I know how to design shift register using flip-flops but I don't know how to do it by RAM. Please explain how to design it using RAM and if possible please provide a good reference so that I know more about it.

Comment: So you want a 1024 bit digital delay line?

Comment: Think about it this way: Each clock cycle you need to put a new bit into the RAM somewhere, and you need to take out the bit you put in 1024 cycles ago. Dual port RAM will make this much easier.

Comment: Hint: Connect your serial input to \$Din_0\$ and the output to \$Dout_{1023}\$. Then connect \$Din_i\$ to \$Dout_{i-1}\$. Then think about the logic of how to play with the address lines and the R/W signal (yeah, assuming dual port RAM).

Comment: @ratchet sir ,sorry I don't know about delay line... here, I want to design a 1024 bit unidirectional shift register using RAM..I only know how to design n-bit shift register using n flip-flops.It was a  GATE 1991 question..I have searched on internet but I didn't get any reference for it that's why I asked here.

Comment: Not everything has "references" sometimes an exercise is just asking you to *think*.

Comment: I suggest you to start with 4 x 1 bit RAM, get the idea and go to whatever size is needed.

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Answer (score -2):

For a fixed length FIFO, you'll have a single 10-bit counter to generate addresses.  The first 1024 bits out will be uninitialized.  For every read/write command (I assume the one input triggers both functions) increment the address.

Comment: Nothing about read/write activity or control, downvoting until substantially improved I'm afraid.